# What does Gaun's Pledge do?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I just noticed the ring Gaun's Pledge in my inventory, I suspect it appeared because the Preorder Bonus DLC was installed.

From the description I gather that it provides protection in some form, but the description of the actual bonus is rather annoyingly useless:

> Gaun's Pledge: Grants Gaun's Pledge

[image]

I didn't notice any attributes changing when I equipped the ring. So what does Gaun's Pledge do and exactly what bonus does it provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gaun's Pledge is a new ability that you'll see as usable on your characters hotbar.

Using Gaun's Pledge restores a small amount of Endurance, and it's usable twice per rest.

[image]